# Not able to import decorate from mobx

Tags: node.js, reactjs, decorator, mobx

Attempted import error: 'decorate' is not exported from 'mobx'.
My mobx version is 6.0, I tried to change the package from mobx to mobx-react, mobx-react-lite,mobx-decorate.But still couldn't resolve it.

Thanks in advance

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T53p6.png)

Comment: Please don't upload images, if possible paster error and code here.

Answer (score 14):

The `decorate` API has been removed in MobX 6, and needs to be replaced by `makeObservable` in the constructor of the targeted class. It accepts the same arguments.

Example:

```
import { makeObservable, observable, computed, action } from "mobx"

class Doubler {
    value = 0

    constructor(value) {
        makeObservable(this, {
            value: observable,
            double: computed,
            increment: action
        })
        this.value = value
    }

    get double() {
        return this.value * 2
    }

    increment() {
        this.value++
    }
}
```

There is also new thing `makeAutoObservable`, you don't even need to use decorators with it:

```
import { makeAutoObservable } from "mobx"

class Timer {
    // You don't even need to use decorators anymore
    // property automatically becomes observable
    secondsPassed = 0

    constructor() {
        // Call it here
        makeAutoObservable(this)
    }

    // And this one automatically becomes an action
    increaseTimer() {
        this.secondsPassed += 1
    }
}
```

More info here:

https://mobx.js.org/react-integration.html

https://mobx.js.org/migrating-from-4-or-5.html

Comment: Even after changing from decorate to makeAutoObservable
getting error "[MobX] 'makeAutoObservable' can only be used for classes that don't have a superclass"



My code :

import { observable, action, makeAutoObservable } from "mobx";
class ConversionsStore {
  conversions = [];
  setConversions(conversions) {
    this.conversions = conversions;
  }
}
ConversionsStore = makeAutoObservable(ConversionsStore, {
  conversions: observable,
  setConversions: action
});
export { ConversionsStore };

Comment: As I said in the answer you need to do it in the constructor of the targeted class